# Accessing Google Fit REST API using Python

Tags: android, python, rest, google-api, google-fit

I would like to use Google Fit REST API at the server and perform CRUD operation on Fit data. A user is authenticated, permissions for https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.activity.write,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.body.read,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.body.write have been granted for fit data to the app. Once the user is authenticated the server receives UID and OAUTH_TOKEN.

```
UID = "XYZ"
OAUTH_TOKEN="FOO_BAR"
APP_SECRET_KEY = "XXX"
CLIENT_ID = "AAA"
```

But whenever I do get/post on rest API it throws 401 error.

```
import requests
url = "https://www.googleapis.com/fitness/v1/users/%s/dataSources"% UID

headers = {'content-type': 'application/json','Authorization': "Bearer %s" % token}
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

print r.status_code
print r.content
```

Output

```
401
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "authError",
    "message": "Invalid Credentials",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Invalid Credentials"
 }
}
```

This is supposed to list all available data sources as mentioned in https://developers.google.com/fit/rest/v1/get-started.

What's wrong here?

Comment: Authorization should be passed via headers as well

Comment: @akash93 still same error.

Comment: Also from the link you posted the authorization needs to be passed in the format `Authorization : Bearer $ACCESS_TOKEN`. Try the curl request given in the documentation to debug

Comment: nothing works literally.

Comment: Based from the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/handle-errors#401_invalid_credentials) about your error, suggested action is to refresh the access token using the long-lived refresh token. If this fails, direct through the OAuth flow. You may check the [example](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/apis/fitness/v1) for more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After spending many hours the solution to the problem is as follows.

UserId should be **`me`** and access_token should be the latest one since access token gets expires in 60 minutes.

```
UID = "XYZ"
OAUTH_TOKEN="FOO_BAR"
APP_SECRET_KEY = "XXX"
CLIENT_ID = "AAA"

import requests
url = "https://www.googleapis.com/fitness/v1/users/me/dataSources"

headers = { 'content-type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer %s' % OAUTH_TOKEN }
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

print r.status_code
print r.content
```